Solution to system of O-U processes
I am trying to solve this O-U process for which the long term mean is another O-U process.
$$
dX(t) = -\alpha_{x} X(t)dt + Y(t)dt + \sigma_{x} dW_{x}(t)
$$
$$
dY(t) = -\alpha_{y}Y(t)dt + \sigma_{y}dW_{y}(t)
$$
Solving for Y(t) is straightforward.
$$
Y(t) = e^{-\alpha_{y}*(t-s)}Y(s) + \sigma_{y} \int_{s}^{t}e^{-\alpha_{y}(t-u)}dW_{y}(u)
$$
However, I struggle when plugging it in the first equation and trying to solve for X(t). Could anyone help me with this?
In general, I struggle when looking at problems in which one process depends on another. What should be the general way to approach these types of problems?
Thanks!

Solving the first SDE is also straightforward leaving the notation $Y(t)$  as an abbreviation in that solution. "Plugging in" the explicit form of $Y(t)$ that you found has no advantage whatsoever.

The solution to general linear SDE
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}X_t = (a(t)X_t+ b(t)) \mathrm{d}t + (g(t)X_t+ h(t))\mathrm{d}B_t 
\end{align*}
is solved here Solution to General Linear SDE. In your case, you let $b(t)=e^{-a_y t}Y_0+ \sigma_{y} \int_{0}^{t}e^{-\alpha_{y}(t-u)}dW_{y}(u)$ (even though it is random, the proof using an integrating-factor still goes through) to get
\begin{align*}
X_t = & X_0 e^{ -a_x t}+ e^{ -a_x t}\left( \int_0^t e^{ a_x s}b(s) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t e^{ a_x s}\sigma_x \mathrm{d}B_s\right).
\end{align*}

This solution looks strange. In OP's case we have $g(t)=0$ so I would have thought with time dependent coefficients it is
$$
X_t=e^{\int_0^ta(u),du}\left{X_0+\int_0^te^{-\int_0^sa(u),du}b(s),ds+\int_0^te^{-\int_0^sa(u),du}h(s),dB_s\right}
$$
This is a special case of this. Since OP has constant $a(u)$ equal to $-a_x$ and constant $h(s)$ equal to $\sigma_x$ this can be simplified a bit but I cannot see how to get your expression.

@KurtG. you are right, I used the wrong case. I will fix it.

ok i fixed it to the right case.
